# ERROR :Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: java, android

When I try to build my project, the Messages Gradle Build reports these messages:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)

Gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bolt.skola"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.9'


compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'



testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: are you sure that SDK version is installed in your SDK Manager? try to edit your buildToolsVersion :)

Comment: Yes it is... This hapend after today's patch...

Comment: All seems fine to me. I'm using it as well. Clean and Re- build project once.

Comment: I tried to clean and rebuild, but nothing..

Comment: try to sync your gradle :) Sync Project Gradle or alt + g then try to run it again :)

Comment: Of course i tried to sync but no help:(

Comment: Had the same problem and this was the cause:

Answer (score 0):

I edited my package name to solve the problem.

Comment: This should have been a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: This doen't solve the issue. You have to find the root of the issue first.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have an item in your XML without a proper ID

```
<Button android:id="@+id/"/>
```

It's hard for the compiler to detect the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Manifest file and check the package name -

package="com.shaon.rastarchele.leet.subcse"> like this

for example see the image attach

[image]